# Symfony Form with subform

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I have a user form and a contact form in my user form i tried to add my contact form to the user form

When I tried to add

```
$builder->add(
            'contact',
            new ContactType()
        );
```

It failed with

```
You cannot add children to a simple form.
Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?
```

tried to set the compound but didnt work

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $defaults = array(
        'compound' => true,
        'inherit_data' => true,
    );

    $resolver->setDefaults($defaults);
}
```

Comment: The contact belongs to an user? Has it a relation with user? if the answer is no, you have to add $builder->add(
            'contact',
            new ContactType(), array('mapped' => false)
        );

Comment: it had an relation but did accidently overwrite the getParent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `compound` option is by default set to `true`.

1. How did you extend your form type class? `AbstractFormType`, or something else?
2. Did you override `getParent()` method?

This could explain `compound` being set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Thought I did delete the parent but did forget to delete my custom getParent in my own abstract type.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a question about extending. It should be `AbstractType` while me accidentally extended wrong class and I got the error from the original question.